# Preventing the user to re-open(click) a button after certain forms filled up

Tags: php, forms, href

I have a Management Information System for our Software Engineering. Here's what I want to happen. After I enter the customer's basic info, his/her record (with ID) will show up in the customer list. And next to it are 2 buttons, first button is for 'Contract 1' and the second one is 'Contract 2'. After I filled up either one of the contracts, I want the button not to be clickable.

(Another explanation)
If a contract is empty, make the 'button' clickable so the user can add. But after it is filled, the button will not be accessible anymore.

I think you may need this code

```
<?php
                    include 'connect-db.php';
                ?>

                <table class="myTable" width="80%">


                    <th width="5%">Customer<br>Number</th>
                    <th>CRC</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Service<br>Contract</th>
                    <th>Chapel<br>Contract</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY CustomerNumber DESC LIMIT 5";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?=$row['CustomerNumber']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['CRC']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['Name']?></td>
                                <td>
                                    **<a href="editprocess-service.php?CustomerNumber=<?=$row['CustomerNumber']?>">Add</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="editprocess-chapel.php?CustomerNumber=<?=$row['CustomerNumber']?>">Add</a>
                                </td>**

                            </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
    </table>
    <br>        
    <a href="masterlist.php"><input type="button" value="New Record" style="margin-left: 785px;"></a>
```

The codes in bold is where I want the magic to happen. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you store the contract information in a table field then you can use PHP functions to check if value is set.

```
if(isset($row['contract'])) {
     //echo disabled button
} else {
     //eco interactable button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply disable onclick

```
<button id="myBtn"onclick="myFunction()">My Button</button>
```